# Is there something different between these code bases?

Tags: c++

I'm updating a mod of a program to a new version. From what I can see, they have the same code for the `PlayerControl__Class` struct and the `PlayerControl__StaticFields` struct, but JetBrains Rider For Unreal Engine is giving me `Cannot use '->' to access member of a class which doesn't overload 'operator ->'` Here's the line that gives the error:

```cpp
auto playerList = (*PlayerControl__TypeInfo)->static_fields->AllPlayerControls;
```

Here are the new struct definitions:

```cpp
struct PlayerControl__StaticFields {
    struct PlayerControl *LocalPlayer;
    struct GameOptionsData *GameOptions;
    struct List_1_PlayerControl_ *AllPlayerControls;
};

struct PlayerControl__Class {
    Il2CppClass_0 _0;
    Il2CppRuntimeInterfaceOffsetPair *interfaceOffsets;
    struct PlayerControl__StaticFields *static_fields;
    const Il2CppRGCTXData *rgctx_data;
    Il2CppClass_1 _1;
    struct PlayerControl__VTable vtable;
};
```

And here are the old:

```cpp
struct PlayerControl__StaticFields {
    struct PlayerControl *LocalPlayer;
    struct GameOptionsData *GameOptions;
    struct List_1_PlayerControl_ *AllPlayerControls;
};

struct PlayerControl__Class {
    Il2CppClass_0 _0;
    Il2CppRuntimeInterfaceOffsetPair *interfaceOffsets;
    struct PlayerControl__StaticFields *static_fields;
    const Il2CppRGCTXData *rgctx_data;
    Il2CppClass_1 _1;
    struct PlayerControl__VTable vtable;
};
```

Am I missing anything?

Comment: C doesn't have operator overloads. Perhaps you should remove the [tag:c] tag.

Comment: What is the type of `PlayerControl__TypeInfo`? You are doubly dereferencing it, so I guess it has type `PlayerControl__Class **`?

Comment: The two code snippets (new and old) are strictly identical.

Comment: Beyond Compare used to have a free version.  It may still have a trial period

Comment: [No](https://www.diffchecker.com/b3gSQckZ)